# На странице сайта выводится ошибка Undefined variable str in /avreloadrd.php on line 148

Tags: php, joomla

Ошибка как я понимаю здесь.

```
$alt = JText::_('WARN_FLASH_ALT', true);
        if ($alt == 'WARN_FLASH_ALT') {
            // Fallback if no translation is available.
            $alt = 'Get Adobe Flash Player here';
        }
148        $ret = array($str, '<script 
       type="text/javascript">window.addEvent("domready",function(){var s = 
       "warnflash%s"; if ($(s)){$(s).setOpacity(1);}});</script>');
        return $ret;
    }

    /**
     * Local initialization
     */
```

Вот так это более точно выглядит по строкам:
[image: Так построчно расположены команды avreloaded.php]

Помогите разобраться. Заранее благодарен. С уважением. Игорь.

Comment: Не определённая переменная $str. Смотрите выше по коду в данной функции. Если нет объявления переменной и она не передаётся в параметрах функции - значит надо логически правильно её объявить. Как? Это надо смотреть, что вообще делает этот класс и в частности данная функция.

Answer (score 1):

У вас не определена переменная `$str` на данном участке кода. Необходимо её определить. (Возможно, в вашем случае вы хотели написать вместо неё `$alt`);